# Makefile producing some, but not all .o files

Tags: makefile

My makefile is producing 5/7 .o files. Any idea why it refuses to make entry.o and productiondb.o? Note: both entry.cpp and production.cpp are present in the file.

```
      asgmt01: showreport.o entry.o reporter.o productiondb.o stationdata.o yeardata.o resourcecount.o entry.h reporter.h productiondb.h stationdata.h yeardata.h resourcecount.h
           g++ showreport.o entry.o reporter.o productiondb.o stationdata.o yeardata.o resourcecount.o -g -Wall -o asgmt01

      entry.o:  entry.h

      reporter.o:  reporter.h

      productiondb.o:  productiondb.h

      stationdata.o:  stationdata.h

      yeardata.o:  yeardata.h

      resourcecount.o: resourcecount.h

      .PHONY: x
      x:           #cleanthe directory
           rm -f *.o asgmt01
```

Should be compiling, but I get this result:

make

g++    -c -o showreport.o showreport.cpp

g++    -c -o reporter.o reporter.cpp

g++    -c -o stationdata.o stationdata.cpp

g++    -c -o yeardata.o yeardata.cpp

g++    -c -o resourcecount.o resourcecount.cpp

g++ showreport.o entry.o reporter.o productiondb.o stationdata.o yeardata.o 
       resourcecount.o -g -Wall -o asgmt01

g++: error: entry.o: No such file or directory

g++: error: productiondb.o: No such file or directory

make: *** [asgmt01] Error 1

```
  update:

  asgmt01: productiondb.o stationdata.o yeardata.o resourcecount.o entry.o reporter.o showreport.o productiondb.h stationdata.h yeardata.h resourcecount.h entry.h reporter.h
        g++ productiondb.o stationdata.o yeardata.o resourcecount.o entry.o reporter.o showreport.o -g -Wall -o asgmt01
  productiondb.o:  productiondb.cpp productiondb.h
        g++ -g productiondb.cpp productiondb.h -o productiondb.o
  stationdata.o:  stationdata.cpp stationdata.h
        g++ -g stationdata.cpp stationdata.h -o stationdata.o
  yeardata.o:  yeardata.cpp yeardata.h
        g++ -g yeardata.cpp yeardata.h -o yeardata.o
  resourcecount.o: resourcecount.cpp resourcecount.h 
        g++ -g resourcecount.cpp resourcecount.h -o resourcecount.o
  entry.o:  entry.cpp entry.h
        g++ -g entry.cpp entry.h -o entry.o
  reporter.o:  reporter.cpp reporter.h
        g++ -g reporter.cpp reporter.h -o reporter.o
  showreport.o: showreport.cpp
        g++ -g showreport.cpp -o showreport.o
  .PHONY: x
  x:           #cleanthe directory
        rm -f *.o asgmt01
```

result:

g++ -g productiondb.cpp productiondb.h -o productiondb.o

/usr/lib/../lib64/crt1.o: In function `_start':

/home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/glibc-2.18/csu/../sysdeps/x86_64/start.S:118: undefined reference to `main'

/tmp/cc95fNHG.o: In function `productiondb::productiondb()':

/home/student/matthew.cole3/cs261/production/productiondb.cpp:9: undefined reference to `StationData::StationData()'

/home/student/matthew.cole3/cs261/production/productiondb.cpp:9: undefined reference to `StationData::~StationData()'

/tmp/cc95fNHG.o: In function `productiondb::~productiondb()':

/home/student/matthew.cole3/cs261/production/productiondb.cpp:17: undefined reference to `StationData::~StationData()'

/tmp/cc95fNHG.o: In function `productiondb::addData(entry const&)':

/home/student/matthew.cole3/cs261/production/productiondb.cpp:24: undefined reference to `StationData::add(entry const&)'

/home/student/matthew.cole3/cs261/production/productiondb.cpp:27: undefined reference to `StationData::add(entry const&)'

/home/student/matthew.cole3/cs261/production/productiondb.cpp:30: undefined reference to `StationData::add(entry const&)'

/home/student/matthew.cole3/cs261/production/productiondb.cpp:33: undefined reference to `StationData::add(entry const&)'

/home/student/matthew.cole3/cs261/production/productiondb.cpp:36: undefined reference to `StationData::add(entry const&)'

/tmp/cc95fNHG.o:/home/student/matthew.cole3/cs261/production/productiondb.cpp:39: more undefined references to `StationData::add(entry const&)' follow

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

make: *** [productiondb.o] Error 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canonically, each entry of the Makefile should provide the build command, like this:

```
entry.o: entry.cpp entry.h
    g++ -c $< -o $@
```

where the variable `$<` refers to the first input, `entry.cpp`; `$@` refers to the output name, `entry.o`; and `entry.h` is listed as an additional dependency, so Make will rebuild `entry.o` if either `entry.{cpp,h}` change.
Since your Makefile entries are incomplete, they don't build.

Comment: That seemed to have solved that problem, but now regardless of the order, the very first .o file errors and says "undefined reference to main"

Comment: Can you post the updated Makefile? If you have `g++ -c`, it shouldn't care about main...

Comment: Thanks. The errors stem from including the `.h` files in the `g++` command. For example, in the new Makefile, you've written
`g++ -c entry.cpp entry.h ...`
Instead, use either
`g++ -c $<` or `g++ -c entry.cpp`
(without the headers).

Comment: that got it! Thanks, Trevor!

Comment: Awesome. Would you mind accepting the original answer?

Comment: There is absolutely no need to provide the full command line.  Make contains built-in rules to build many things, including compiling object files from C++ source files, which it will happily use if you don't provide your own.  You can customize how these built-in rules work by modifying standard variables like `CXX`, `CXXFLAGS`, etc.